# Add SPEEX code support to FFMPEG

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, flv, codec, speex

How can I add SPEEX support to my FFMPEG installation? I need to extract the audio from a FLV created by FMS.

I just installed it using: app-get install ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -version
FFmpeg version SVN-rUNKNOWN, Copyright (c) 2000-2007 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-pp --enable-swscaler --enable-pthreads --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libogg --enable-libgsm --enable-dc1394 --disable-debug --enable-shared --prefix=/usr
  libavutil version: 1d.49.3.0
  libavcodec version: 1d.51.38.0
  libavformat version: 1d.51.10.0
  built on Apr 23 2010 15:11:13, gcc: 4.2.4 (Ubuntu 4.2.4-1ubuntu3)
ffmpeg      SVN-rUNKNOWN
libavutil   3212032
libavcodec  3352064
libavformat 3344896
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could get it working without libspeex. I found that if I don't change the mix rate of the flash/flex application, I can extract the audio from it using mp3lame!!!