# ffmpeg: execute with more options

Tags: command-line, compiler-construction, ffmpeg

I installed FFMPEG using apt-get. It comes by default compiled with some options:

```
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-pp --enable-swscaler --enable-pthreads
      --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libogg --enable-libgsm
      --enable-dc1394 --disable-debug --enable-shared --prefix=/usr
```

How can I execute it and add more options without recompiling it? I'm looking for a way to execute including the option: `-enable libspeex1`.

Comment: This is a duplicate of your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877259/add-speex-code-support-to-ffmpeg).  Also, you should say what OS and version you're using.

Comment: not really the same question. I'm asking here how to execute FFMPEG with different option without recompiling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't.  Changing those options requires recompiling.